# x86_64 Assembly double comparison not working as intended, some of the time

Tags: assembly, floating-point, double, x86-64

I'm aware of floating point inaccuracies, but I need a way around them.

So, I need to do a graph traversal, and I'm doing it by getting all the nodes into the stack, adding routes to all the neighbors, then adding a large route to all the non-neighbors, finally going through and finding the best routes. It works fine for the routes that were created from the neighbors, but it breaks on the routes that were created with a large number.

Here's the relevant sections of code.

Here the large route is assigned.

```
movsd xmm0, [big]
mov [r11+rax+TAR], r9
movsd [r11+rax+DIS], xmm0
mov [r11+rax+HOP], r9
```

Here the comparison is made, in order to see if a better route is found.

```
ucomisd xmm0, xmm2
ja  bMBD
jmp eMBD
bMBD:
    mov rax, [r8+ROT]
    mov [rax+r13+HOP], r11
    movsd [rax+r13+DIS], xmm2
eMBD:
```

The above block of code is where the problem is, following is a breakdown of what I believe the code is doing.

> D asks D for better route, but nothing happens: good.
>
> D asks A, finds one and calculates distance as 3.3+5.4=8.7, it's better and replaces it's current route: good.
>
> D asks B, finds one with a distance of 8.7+0=8.7. For some reason this is regarded as better and it's route is replaced: bad.

So, why is the `ja` condition returning that 8.7 > 8.7, but only on the routes that had their distance initialized to a large number (I've tried reducing the size of the number, but that has yielded the same results)?

Thank You.

Comment: Post debugger output after the `ucomisd` instruction, showing `xmm0`, `xmm2` and `eflags`.

Comment: If that's hand-tuned asm, beware that indexed addressing modes like `[r11+rax+TAR]` [don't stay micro-fused in the out-of-order core for Intel CPUs pre-SKL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046634/micro-fusion-and-addressing-modes/31027695#31027695).  So you'd actually save a fused-domain uop by using an ALU instruction to calculate an address in a register, so then all three stores could micro-fuse.  If you don't have a spare register, or ALU uops are a bottleneck but the frontend (total fused-domain uops) isn't, then you shouldn't change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rounding differences are a fact of life in floating point math. This is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

If you only need to find *any* one of the best routes, then I see no problem in `3.3 + 5.4 > 8.7 + 0.0`; either one of the routes is fine.

If you need to retrieve *all* routes that share the same optimal distance, then I agree you really need `3.3 + 5.4` to be equal to `8.7 + 0.0`.
There are a few ways to accomplish this; see below. For sample code, I will be using pseudo code rather than assembly, since this issue is not specific to any language.

### 1. Ignore minor differences

Consider numbers to be equal if the absolute value of their difference is less than a certain small number (e.g. 0.001).
This means the comparison logic becomes slightly more complex.
Instead of:

```
if x < y then
    return LESS_THAN
elseif x > y then
    return GREATER_THAN
else
    return EQUAL
```

you would be doing:

```
epsilon = 0.001
if x < y - epsilon then
    return LESS_THAN
elseif x > y + epsilon then
    return GREATER_THAN
else
    return EQUAL
```

### 2. Use fixed point numbers

This is easier than it sounds; just multiply everything with a certain factor that will eliminate the fractional part of every number, and perform all your calculations based on integers rather than floats.

For distances `NNNN.N` (i.e. no more than one decimal digit behind the decimal point), this factor is 10.

So instead of:

```
routeA = 3.3 + 5.4
routeB = 8.7 + 0.0
if routeA > routeB then ...
```

you would be doing:

```
routeA = 33 + 54
routeB = 87 + 0
if routeA > routeB then ...
```